# Can't remove margins on react web app

Tags: css, reactjs, react-redux

I am having trouble removing these huge white margins on my react project. Below are some of the solutions I have tried.

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

/-/-/-/

```
body {
  max-width: 2040px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 5%;
  clear: both;
}
```

I have tried every variation. My only installed dependencies that should affect anything CSS wise is bootstrap and I don't think thats it. I tried adjusting `max-width` to a value of `2040px` just to test if it would work and there appears to be a limit to which I can set the width. Help would be appreciated.

I should also mention that this is persistent throughout the entire page. This issue is not limited to the background image which I am linking in the `css` file
[White Margins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rfo6N.jpg)

Comment: "My only installed dependencies that should affect anything CSS wise is bootstrap and I don't think thats it." - Bootstrap is a CSS grid framework that controls many aspects of your page layout. If you don't understand its grid system, you should read up on it more. Try removing the line where you call Bootstrap to see if your gutters go away.

Comment: Thank you @JonUleis for the response. I looked at the documentation and a solution I found was to add `container-fluid` as a class to the parent div. This did not work.

Comment: are you using bootstrap 4?

Answer (score 10):

All the browsers uses different default margins, which causing sites look different in the other browser.

The `*` is `wildcard`, means `all elements` present in our site (consider as [universal selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors)), so we are setting each and every element in our site to have **zero margin, and zero padding**, to make the site look the same in every browsers.

If your style not getting applied then you can use `!important` to override style,

```
* {    
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you created it using create-react-app there will probably be a file `public/index.html`.

There is a  tag wrapped around the root where React will inject you App.

Usually the browser style-sheet set the margin of `<body>` to [8px](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp).
That's most likely that white margin around your App that you're struggling to get rid off.

To remove it, one option is to open `public/index.html` and set the margin to 0 using inline styles like this:

```
<body style=margin:0>
```

In case you're using `@emotion/react` for styling you may alternatively (still assuming that there is this body tag in `public/index.html`) leave it as `<body>` and use the [`<Global>` component](https://emotion.sh/docs/globals) to define styles for `<body>`. Something like this in your `App.js`:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Global
        styles={css`
          body {
            margin: 0;
          }
        `}
      />
      <Your />
      <Other />
      <Components />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @emotion/react / mui 5 apply a top margin of 21px by default, do you know why is that?

Answer (score 2):

If you try:

```
* {    
margin: 0 !important;
padding: 0 !important;}
```

You may have some issues. As I was using some mui, so this was distorting my components. I may recomend to modify the "body" in public/index.html using:

```
<body style=margin:0>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply add to the app.css or your main CSS file
`body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }`

Comment: As he is using bootstrap dependency in his app, so you can't assign margin and padding without adding `!Important`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

User agent style sheet overrides the custom style. You can override this using !important in normal html and css

It is better to user react spacing library, rather than overriding the user default style sheet https://material-ui.com/system/spacing/

or you can use the following

```
<body id="body">
<div id="appRoot"></div>
</body>
```

style sheet

```
body
  margin: 0
  padding: 0
button
  padding: 10px 20px 
  border-radius: 5px
  outline: none
```

React JS code blocks

```
class A extends React.Component{  
  componentWillMount(){
    document.getElementById('body').className='darktheme'
  }
    componentWillUnmount(){
    document.getElementById('body').className=''
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div> Component A </div>
    )
  }
}
class App extends React.Component{  
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      isAMount: false
    }
  }

  handleClick(){
    this.setState({
      isAMount: !this.state.isAMount
    })
  }

  render(){
    return (
    <div> 
        <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}> Click Me</button> 
        <div> App </div>
        <hr />
        <div> {this.state.isAMount && <A /> } </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('appRoot'))
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using background image. Its problem due to image size ratio.

You have to use background-size: cover property in css.

Also use appropriate background-position to make sure the gavel comes in center bottom of page.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to add a background image in my react app but react left some margin on top and left.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
      background: {
        backgroundImage:  `url(${Image})`,
        backgroundPosition: 'center',
        backgroundSize: 'cover',
        backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
        width: '100vw',
        height: '95vh',
      }
```

After reading the documentation, I realized that it was not margin, but  positioning of the image. Setting the `position:fixed` with `top:0` and `left:0` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the answers above and trying them I have concluded that the best way is to keep your index.css(note: that the index.css in particular has the margins already set to 0 globally.) and App.css files that are auto generated when you "npx create-react-app".

I have noticed that many beginner tutorials tell you to remove these files and more, but after facing this problem it is honestly easier to just edit the boilerplate than start from scratch.

Answer (score -1):

`* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` override by browser.

try

```
html,body{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
```